# How Do I Send Multiple Threads In Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to be able to receive a list of content when posting data from an input. The input is in a text file which will be opened in python. To speed the process up I'd like to increase the number of threads that can be sent at once. How would I be able to do that, here's a rough idea of what I'm talking about:

```
import requests

userdata = open("data.txt", "r")
usercodes = [x.strip() for x in userdata]

for i in range(len(usercodes)):
    thread_one = requests.post(url='https://test.com/input', params=usercodes[i])
    thread_two = requests.post(url='https://test.com/input', params=usercodes[i+1])
    thread_three = requests.post(url='https://test.com/input', params=usercodes[i+2])
```

I want all the threads to run at the same time as in here the program will carry out the requests one after the next.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from multiprocessing import Pool

def make_request(usercode):
    requests.post(url='https://test.com/input', params=usercode)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    userdata = open("data.txt", "r")
    usercodes = [x.strip() for x in userdata]

    with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
        print(p.map(make_request, usercodes))

    p.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
import requests

userdata = open("data.txt", "r")
usercodes = (x.strip() for x in userdata)  # keep as generator

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
    pool.map(partial(requests.post, 'https://test.com/input'), usercodes)
    userdata.close()   # closing the input file
```

Answer (score 0):

Async is definitely your friend here.

```
from gevent import joinall, spawn, monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import requests

userdata = open("data.txt", "r")
usercodes = [x.strip() for x in userdata]

send_url = 'https://test.com/input'
threads = []

def send(usercode):
   requests.post(url=send_url, params=usercode)

for code in usercodes:
    threads.append(spawn(send, code))

joinall(threads)
```

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error for monkey after I installed gevent.

Comment: Did you install with pip?  What version?

Comment: My pip version is 9.0.1 and my python version is 3.6

Comment: Well I sent you the documentation on how to use that.  Make sure Monkey patch is done as the very first thing happening in your code base.

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out